# How to let selected role submit multiple data for 1 node?

Tags: entities

I want to do a product price compare site. So a product is a node and product can have many different price at different store. I want to allow selected user's role able to submit new price or new store from time to time but I want them to submit data on the node page similar to submitting comments, NOT on node edit page.

I'm looking onto entityreference but i'm not sure where to start and what others module needed to accomplish my objective.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You will need to get a form onto the node page. It does not need to be the node form - you can design something custom. Else a link to a form.

Answer (score 0):

The Field Collection module will let you do a couple of helpful things here:

- you can group a set of fields, ie store name, price so that this data is part of the same entity
- you can embed links to add/edit/delete field collections right on the node.

Embedding the form in the node is trickier, but doable, and Field Collection will get you off to a good start.

Once the Field Collection module is enabled, create a field of the type field collection on your content type. Set the widget to 'embedded'. Then go and add individual fields to your content type.

There is basic documentation at https://www.drupal.org/node/1353926 and a video tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1V1ofpgUw-Y.